# Jquery each function not working for string indexed arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iteration

I'm not being able to get the $.each() jquery function working with string indexed arrays, any idea on whats wrong?

Example @ JSFiddle --> 
http://jsfiddle.net/WKDUA/

Code:

```
var firstArray = [52, 33];

document.writeln("First Array:\n<ul>");
$.each(firstArray, function(key, value)
{
    document.writeln('<li>[' + key + ']: ' + value + "</li>\n");
});
document.writeln("</ul>\n");


var secondArray = new Array();

secondArray['first'] = 'foo';
secondArray['second'] = 'bar';

document.writeln("Second Array:\n<ul>");
$.each(secondArray, function(key, value)
{
    document.writeln('<li>[' + key + ']: ' + value + "</li>\n");
});
document.writeln("</ul>\n");
```

Output:

```
First Array:
   [0]: 52
   [1]: 33
Second Array:
```

Comment: its actually an object, not array

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is always indexed by an integer representing the position of an element.

You're looking for an [*object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals) whose properties you can access via bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};

obj['first'] = 'foo';
obj['second'] = 'bar';

document.writeln("Second Array:\n<ul>");
$.each(obj, function(key, value)
{
    document.writeln('<li>[' + key + ']: ' + value + "</li>\n");
});
document.writeln("</ul>\n");
```

In your original code, the `$.each` block was never being entered because you did not add any elements to the array. You *did* define properties `first` and `second` on that array and assign them values.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ddTPu/

Comment: A funny thing is, when you start this script badly with `var obj = [];` instead of `var obj = {};`, you CAN console.log your ?array? with length 0 but having indexed contents, but cannot loop through it as through object with `$.each()`. Wonder what instace I have really created.

Answer (score 4):

String indexed arrays(a.k.a. associative arrays) are objects, and not arrays.
An array cannot have anything than number as indexes(it can even be Math.PI, because it is a number).
The solution is to declare your secondArray as an object :

```
var secondArray = {};// or var secondArray = new Object();
```

You can see [here a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/WKDUA/3/).